# How to set netbeans default for php files in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans

I want to set netbeanse as default for php files ie when I double click .php file it should open in Netbeans.
Even php file not showing open with netbeans options. It's opening with gedit.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click a php file, properties, open with.

If this doesn't help there are other ways to do this listed here
https://askubuntu.com/questions/90214/how-to-set-default-program

Comment: thanks but Netbeans not showing in open with options.

Answer (score 0):

OK I have done it. Steps:
1. open netbeans.desktop using

```
    sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/netbeans.desktop
```

2. adding %U at the end of exec line:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=NetBeans
   Comment=Integrated Development Environment
   Comment[de]=Integrierte Entwicklungsumgebung
   Exec=netbeans %U
   Icon=netbeans
   Categories=Development;IDE;`Java`;
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Keywords=development;Java;IDE;platform;javafx;javase;
   ```
3. then save and make it default from properties of php file using right click on .php file.